# How to repeat formula in a column using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, repeat

How can I repeat a fomula in a column? The fomula adds-up first 3 monthly values to get Quarterly in next column, then should move to next 3 values and so on.

Could you pelase help me? Thanks!

1. 76
2. 70
3. 85
4. 91
5. 89
6. 76
7. 80
8. 66
9. 83

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sumer()
For i = 1 To 23 Step 3
Range("b" & i + 2).Value = Range("a" & i).Value + Range("a" & i + 1).Value +Range("a" & i + 2).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

let me know if this has answered your question

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SumQtr()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastRow Step 3
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 2, 2).Value + Cells(i - 1, 2).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```